# How to regsub change string and leave part of him?

Tags: tcl

How can I change name mta429 to be "\033[42mmta429\033[0m" (for coloring print)?
I tried several ways with regsub and string map but none of my tries I succeeded to leave the number.

`61826340   24.0   NA          r       20/10   00:01   main   mta429   1       sc_split.bash                flow/all`

Comment: Please share what you _have_ tried.  It could be something minor in your code that's not quite right.

Comment: The most likely problems are with escaping in strings, as the substituands are a little tricky that way.